# Library's CMake generates DLL. Application's CMake wants LIB

Tags: windows, dll, cmake, lib

My library has minimal, straightforward CMake code with the pertinent lines

```
add_library(MyLib <sources>)

install(
    TARGETS MyLib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${destination}/lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${destination}/lib
    COMPONENT Libraries)
install(
    FILES mylib.h
    DESTINATION ${destination}/include
    COMPONENT Headers)
```

When executed under Windows, the system generates `mylib.dll` in `...\build\Release`, and `mylib.lib` and `mylib.exp` (what's that?) in `...\build\lib\Release`. It only installs `mylib.dll`.

My application has minimal, straightforward CMake code to search for my library:

```
find_path(MyLib_INCLUDE_DIR mylib.h)
find_library(MyLib_LIBRARIES NAMES MyLib)
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(MyLib DEFAULT_MSG MyLib_LIBRARIES MyLib_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Which works under Linux, but under Windows results in

```
-- Could NOT find MyLib (missing: MyLib_LIBRARIES)
```

From experimentation I know that this error occurs whenever there is only a `.DLL` file, and no associated `.LIB` import library.

Shall I correct MyLib to install `mylib.lib`? How?

Or is it possible to modify my application so that it is satisfied with `mylib.dll` only? How?

#### Research done so far

This is *not* about static vs dynamic linking ([DLL and LIB files - what and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913691), [cmake link against dll/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392174/)): I want `dynamic linking`; if a `.LIB` file is required, it has nothing to do with static linking.

This link [cmake : shared library : how to get the .lib name instead of .dll name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545720) may be pertinent, but is not explicit enough. Two other questions [CMake generated VS project expecting lib instead of dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53601141/), [Linking dll/lib to a cmake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113883/) seem related, but have no answer.

Comment: reworded side remark, which by no means answers the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command `install` classifies `.lib` file for a shared library as ARCHIVE. This is explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/install.html#installing-targets):

> For DLL platforms (all Windows-based systems including Cygwin), the DLL import library is treated as an `ARCHIVE` target.

So you need to add ARCHIVE clause to `install()` for install `.lib` file as well:

```
install(
    TARGETS MyLib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${destination}/lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${destination}/lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${destination}/bin
    COMPONENT Libraries)
```

---

Not also, that RUNTIME DESTINATION is usually specified as `bin`, the same as destination for *executables*. This helps the executables on Windows to locate the shared libraries (`.dll`).